# Run custom commands on startup on Azure App Service on Linux

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In the Application settings for an App Service on Linux we can specify Startup File
[image]

We are deploying a PHP (Drupal) application. Could I along with this app have a bash script that I would run that would mount a file share to the machine? This share would then be used to store all images, documents and other content.

Comment: Why not to use Azure CDN and/or other storage services?

Comment: @MikeUrnunMSFT How do you mean? You mean to access the configuration files, that the application expects to find on disk, over http?